# Unable to access quick text when logged in as another user of same profile

Tags: casefeed

Quick text is enabled in our org and the OWD is public Read/Write.
I have 2 users of system admin profile say user1 and user2. User1 have created 2 quick text records. These 2 records are not accessible for user2 while tried to use in the feed.

Since the OWD is public Read/Write, user2 should be able to access them. But not sure why this is happening.

Is there any special permission present to access the quick text created by another user? or any work around present for this?

Any suggesstion will be a great help.

Comment: Can you check User2 is marked as "Live Agent User" in User record?

Comment: Do they have any unique permission sets from each other?

Comment: @SantanuBoral : Live agent is not enabled in my org. Does this issue related with enabling Live agent ?

Comment: @caleb.breckon : There are no permission sets at all.